# My iPhone storage keeps melting

Tags: iphone, storage

I'm French excuse me for my English.

I've noticed, since I've updated my iPhone 6 to  iOS 10 that I'm always out of storage.
This is very strange for various reasons and here are some :

- I used to have faaaaaaar more apps (now I only have just a little more than one screen) - starting from home.
- I have 0 pictures/videos.
- No big app (Spotify, Slack, Tinder, Piano Tiles...)
- I used to have instagram, facebook and messenger but since I have this problem, I'm obliged to use Friendly.
- when I delete an app, I see the storage counter in Settings going from (eg.) 134,7Mb to 0Mb in 2 minutes.
- When I count the storage taken by my apps, it's not equal to what is written in the settings (see my screenshot).

As an unfortunate coincidence, the iPhone 7 just came out, that leads me to conclude that Apple damage its old stars (the iPhone 6 in my case) to make us buy the new one.

Why doesn't apple allow us to clean apps cache ?
Why, when I delete an Apple's app, since it is allowed, and then redownload it, the download is not long because... it's instantaneous ? The app is not really erased ?

Does anyone have the same problem or know how to avoid it ? Thanks[image][image][image]

PS : notice the photos app telling that I have 133 and something...mb. I have 0 picture and even deleted the screenshots !

PS2 : I have this iPhone since a little more than a year and it was an iPhone I was given in an Apple Store (Opera) after my other iPhone had a problem. And guess what, this précédent iPhone was, this one too, an exchange!

Comment: It never fails to amaze me that people instantly assume that, rather than there being some bug or issue affecting a small minority of people with a device, the big bad company (Apple in this case) must be rendering their products obsolete through some trickery. I know at least one person on iPhone 6, and another on iPhone 6s, and neither are having this problem with iOS 10. If it were actually a widespread issue that was the result of an intentional action by Apple, there would be pitchfork-wielding villagers burning down Apple HQ right now.

Comment: Apple apps in total take up 150 MB of space on the device. "Deleting" an Apple app simply removes the icon from the home screen. It does not actually remove the app from the device.

Comment: You really need to delete old messages from the Messages app. That's what's taking up your storage.

Comment: @tubedogg : as you can read on a plenty of websites, planned obsolescence is something Apple do. http://thenewdaily.com.au/life/tech/2016/04/18/iphone-life-expectancy/

Comment: I think that instead of reading clickbait articles, I'll instead refer to the 2009 Mac Pro that I'm currently typing this on, the 2007 iMac that my mother uses as her primary computer, and the iPhone 5 that's sitting on my desk, all of which work perfectly wonderfully (as well as the aforementioned iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s). All hardware becomes obsolete at some point. The fact that Apple releases iOS software updates for _four years_ after a device is released indicates that they support their products far longer than any of their competitors do.

Comment: Thankfully Apple no longer offers a 16GB storage option. 16GB was really only good for people who got an iPhone and used it like their old flip phone.

Comment: To this day I still have this issue. Everything listed under manage storage doesn't even add up to half of my phones capacity, yet I have zero kb left.